# Implications of elementary inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, proof-writing

I would like your help to prove that the following statement involving some elementary inequalities is correct (or, if wrong, to construct a counterexample)

Assume
$$
\begin{cases}
Z+X\geq R+W\\
Z+Y\geq R+Q\\
Z\geq R\\
-------\\
Z+X\in [0,1]\\
R+W\in [0,1]\\
Z+Y\in [0,1]\\
R+Q\in [0,1]\\
-------\\
X\in [0,1]\\
Z\in [0,1]\\
W\in [0,1]\\
R\in [0,1]\\
Y\in [0,1]\\
Q\in [0,1]\\
\end{cases}
$$

I want to show  that
$$
Z+X+Y\geq R+W+Q
$$

---

What I have done so far: notice that 
$$
Z+X+Y\equiv Z+X+Z+Y-Z
$$
and
$$
R+W+Q\equiv R+W+R+W-R
$$
I guess that this may help but I can't proceed.

Comment: Counterexample: $Z=\frac{12}{16}, R=\frac{7}{16}, X=Y=\frac{1}{16}, W=Q=\frac{4}{16}$, for which $Z+X+Y=\frac{14}{16}<\frac{15}{16}=R+W+Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let, according to $Z\ge R$, $Z=kR$ for some $k\ge 1$, then from the first two inequalities we have

$$kR+X\geq R+W \implies (k-1)R\ge W-X\tag{1}$$
$$kR+Y\geq R+Q\implies (k-1)R\ge Q-Y\tag{2}$$

and from the required inequality

$$Z+X+Y\ge R+Q+W \implies (k-1)R\ge (Q+W)-(X+Y)\tag{3}$$

From the given conditions we can construct infinitely many solutions indeed for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, for $R$ and $k$ fixed, it suffices satisfy the following

$$\alpha(k-1)R\ge W-X\tag{1'}$$
$$(1-\alpha)(k-1)R\ge Q-Y\tag{2'}$$

inorder to satify also $(3)$.

Let consider for example

- $R=3$ and $k=5$ then $Z=15$ and $(k-1)R=12$
- assume $\alpha =\frac 23$

then we need to satisfy

- $8\ge W-X$
- $4\ge Q-Y$

then select for example

- $W=20,Q=16, X=Y=12$

and we obtain

- $Z+X=27\ge R+W=23$
- $Z+Y=27\ge R+Q=19$
- $Z+X+Y=39\ge R+W+Q=39$

finally to satisfy the condition for tha range it suffices to divide all quantities for

$$d=\max\{Z+X,R+W,Z+Y,R+Q\}=27$$

Comment: I think in $kR+X+Y\ge (2-k)R+Q+W\ge R+Q+W$, the middle term can be the least. Counterexample: $Z=12/16, X=2/16, R=3/16, W=5/16, Y=3/16, Q=1/16$, where $k=4$.

Comment: @farruhota The last inequality is hypotetical and indeed it holds only for $2-k\ge 1$. With k=4 we are of course beyond that limit. Can you find a counterexample for the general statement? That is fo $k\neq 1$? How would you solve that. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @TEX, there is no such restriction on the sum of three numbers in the given system of inequalities.

Comment: @farruhota Therefore it seems confirmed that the inequality $Z+X+Y\geq R+W+Q $ holds only for $Z=R$. Am I wrong?

Comment: my counterexample shows $Z>R$, yet the OP's inequality holds true. So, I think your claim does not hold, no?

Comment: I would say, your claim is the trivial case.

Comment: @farruhota Yes of course! I need to revise that! Thanks

Comment: @farruhota I've fixed with some indication to construct solutions.

Comment: @TEX  I've fixed with some indication to construct solutions.